# Max value after M range in array

Tags: arrays, logic

The problem statement from the https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-value-array-m-range-increment-operations/

> Consider an array of size n with all initial values as 0, we need to
>   perform following m range increment operations.
>
> increment(a, b, k) : Increment values from 'a'
>                        to 'b' by 'k'.     After m operations, we need to calculate the maximum of the values in the array.
>
> Examples:
>
> Input : n = 5 m = 3
>           a = 0, b = 1, k = 100
>           a = 1, b = 4, k = 100
>           a = 2, b = 3, k = 100
>
> Output : 200
>
> Explanation: Initially array = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
>
> After first operation: array = {100, 100, 0, 0, 0}
>
> After second operation: array = {100, 200, 100, 100, 100}
>
> After third operation: array = {100, 200, 200, 200, 100}
>
> Maximum element after m operations  is 200.

Here what I couldn't understand is..

Why we need to take N+1 size and subtract the K value from the upperbound+1 index ?

How this logic giving the correct max value after M operations ?

Could you please anybody help me to understand the logic behind it ?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/9gsrca/algorithm_maximum_value_in_an_array_after_m_range/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x

Comment: above links some what good to explore I felt'